# run local python script inside virtual environment using yaml file

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I want to run my local python script inside virtual environment. Here is the code I have tried.
I have created virtual environment and installed Cassandra-driver as well

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  name: install cassendra-driver
  become: true
  become_user: root
  vars:
    PROJECT_HOME: "/home/hari/Desktop/venvs"
  tasks:
          - name: Run a script using an executable in virtual environment
                    script: "/space/code_base/add_new_column_to_table.py"
                    virtualenv: "{{ PROJECT_HOME }}/myenv"
                    args:
                        executable: python2
```

But I am getting error

- ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/home/hari/Desktop/cassendra-driver_2.yml': line 30, column 27, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
      - name: Run a script using an executable in virtual environment
                script: "/space/code_base/add_new_column_to_table.py"
                      ^ here
```

*

Could some one help me?

My requirement is to run local python script inside virtual environment.

Comment: I suggest you read ["Learn Yaml in Y minutes"](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) where you will learn that yaml is "a strict superset of JSON, with the addition of **syntactically significant newlines and indentation**, like Python". This should help you fix your playbook and this yaml syntax error.

Comment: Thank you. Updated. `ERROR! 'virtualenv' is not a valid attribute for a Task

The error appears to be in '/home/hari/Desktop/cassendra-driver_2.yml': line 29, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

                    virtualenv: "{{ PROJECT_HOME }}/myenv"
          - name: Run a script using an executable in virtual environment
            ^ here

This error can be suppressed as a warning using the "invalid_task_attribute_failed" configuration
`But want to execute my script inside the virtual env.

Comment: for installing Cassandra-driver,m attribute works fine. But for running script is throwing error. Is there any other attribute which can used instead of **virtualenv**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your environment, but something like this should work:

```
tasks:
- command: {{ PROJECT_HOME }}/myenv/bin/python /space/code_base/add_new_column_to_table.py
```